# Get Net Usage for upload using Powershell in Megabit

Tags: powershell

How can I get the Value of network adapter bytes send in Megabit with Powershell.

```
(Get-Counter '\netzwerkadapter(*)\bytes gesendet/s').CounterSamples.CookedValue
```

Have tried to divide through 125000 but get an error.

thanks for a hint.

Comment: Please show the code you're using and show the error message. You can divide by `MB` if needed.  `5242880 / 1MB` for example.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message text (no pictures) into the question.

Comment: If I divide by 1MB i get the Megabyte, isn't it? So I have to multiply with 8.

Comment: Ooops .. I actually missed that you wrote in fact Mega***bit***.   ... yes, then you have to multiply it with 8. 

Answer (score 1):

```
while($true) {
    $date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    $netRateUp =  (Get-Counter '\netzwerkadapter(intel[r] gigabit ct desktop adapter)\bytes gesendet/s').CounterSamples.CookedValue / 1MB * 8
    $date + ' Net: ' + $netRateUp.ToString()
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    }
```

Is the code. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple adapters, your command will return a list of counters. In order to divide them, you either have to pick *one* adapter  or roll the divsion into a for-loop.

For example this works here:

```
(get-counter '\network interface(*)\bytes total/sec').countersamples.cookedvalue | % { $_ / 1MB; }
```

Or if you want to preserve the adapter name, you could use `select` and custom objects like this:

```
(get-counter '\network interface(*)\bytes total/sec').countersamples | 
select @{n="Adapter"; e={$_.instancename}}, @{n="MB/s"; e={$_.cookedvalue/1MB}}
```